# Extract folder name from path in batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to traverse all files within a specific directory and all its subdirectories and then print out the folder name of each file.

I don't know how to get the folder name of each file.

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%x IN ('dir /B /A /S *') DO (
    :: Suppose %%x is 'C:\myfolder\a.txt', the desired output is 'myfolder'
    :: %%~nx is not correct
    echo ???
)
```

Comment: `n` is for file`n`ame. Check `for /?` for other options. You can combine the different options. You probably look for `%%~dpx`

Comment: Did you read the help for the `FOR` command?

Comment: @Squashman "uhh - that is sooo much text..."

Comment: Please note that `DOS` is an Operating System from the 80s/90s! Please use the tag Windows instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
@echo off
FOR /F "delims=" %%F IN ('dir /B /A /S *') DO (
for %%D in ("%%~dpF\.") do echo %%~nxD
)
pause
```

Comment: Your `ECHO` needs the x modifier as well otherwise it will not be able to handle folder names with periods.

Comment: @Squashman you're right, to be honest the first version had that but I forgot what it was for and removed it

Comment: Thanks, this is what I want.

Answer (score 4):

If you want just the path (without drive, without filename), `%%~px` is what you need

If you want just the last folder, not the complete path. This is indeed not that trivial:

```
@echo off 
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%x in ('dir /b /a /s *') do (
  set "line=%%~dpx"
  for /f "delims=" %%y in ("!line:\=.!") do set folder=%%~xy
  echo %%~nxx is in:  !folder:~1!
)
```

Comment: Did I just beat the almighty Stephan by 31 seconds? Oh my.

Comment: "almighty"? There are other names here that come to my mind :D Nevertheless - your's is better (assuming we understood the question right)

Comment: @Stephan, your inner `FOR` can just be this: `for %%y in ("%%~dpx\.") do echo %%~nxy`.  Your inner `FOR` will have problems with Folders that are named with periods.  I just noticed that is what Dennis did but his also suffers from the periods.